# How do I insert a space every four characters in a long line?

Tags: command-line, shell, text-processing

I've got a long line that I want to insert a space every 4 characters, on a single lone line of solid text to make it easier to read, what's the simplest way to do this? also I should be able to input the line from a pipe. e.g.

```
echo "foobarbazblargblurg" | <some command here>
```

gives

```
foob arba zbla rgbl urg
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Use sed as follows:

```
$ echo "foobarbazblargblurg" | sed 's/.\{4\}/& /g'
foob arba zbla rgbl urg
```

Comment: *cursing* that was so close to the `sed` I tried first I could kick myself.

Comment: Just curious, what's the '&' accomplish? Oh, it's a standin for 'the thing what just matched'. Silly me.

Comment: it should be noted that this adds a space at the end as well if there is one more character in the string, which might not be desirable

Comment: @Anubis `'s/.\{4\}/& /g;s/ $//'`

Comment: F*ck it doesn't work in perl.

Comment: @Owl: Perl regexes are probably opposite of sed, you probably need bare `{4}` to act as a counted repeat modifier, instead of `\{4\}`.  Same if you use `sed -E` (extended regexps).

Answer (score 33):

You can use the following simple example:

```
$ echo "foobarbazblargblurg" | fold -w4 | paste -sd' ' -
foob arba zbla rgbl
```

Comment: Very nice...I think this is even better than the `sed` answer.  I didn't know about `fold` before.

Comment: Unfortunately, with current versions of GNU `fold`, it  doesn't work with multi-byte characters (as in `echo €€€€€€€€ | fold -w4 | paste -sd' ' -` in UTF-8).

Answer (score 8):

In bash only, no external commands:

```
str="foobarbazblargblurg"
[[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]
printf "%s%s%s%s " "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
```

or as a one-line pipe version:

```
echo foobarbazblargblurg | 
  { IFS= read -r str; [[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]; \
    printf "%s%s%s%s " "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"; }
```

The way this works is to convert each character of the string to a "(.)" for regex match and capture with `=~`, then just output the captured expressions from  `BASH_REMATCH[]` array, grouped as required. Leading/trailing/intermediate spaces are preserved, remove the quotes around `"${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"` to omit them.

Here it is wrapped up in a function, this one will process its arguments or read stdin if there are no arguments:

```
function fmt4() {
  while IFS= read -r str; do
    [[ $str =~ ${str//?/(.)} ]]
    printf "%s%s%s%s " "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
  done < <( (( $# )) && printf '%s\n' "$@" || printf '%s\n' $(< /dev/stdin) )
}

$ echo foobarbazblargblurg | fmt4
foob arba zbla rgbl urg
```

You can easily parameterise the count to adjust the format string accordingly.

A trailing space is added, use two `printf`s instead of one if that's a problem:

```
printf "%s%s%s%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:4}"
(( ${#BASH_REMATCH[@]} > 5 )) && printf " %s%s%s%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:5}"
```

The first `printf` prints (up to) the first 4 characters, the second conditionally prints all the rest (if any) with a leading space to separate the groups. The test is for 5 elements not 4 to account for the zeroth element.

Notes:

- shell `printf`'s`%c` could be used instead of `%s`, `%c` (maybe) makes the intent clearer, but it's not multi-byte character safe. If your version of bash is capable, the above is all multi-byte character safe.
- shell `printf` reuses its format string until it runs out of arguments, so it just gobbles up 4 arguments at a time, and handles the trailing arguments (so no edge cases needed, unlike some of the other answers here which are arguably wrong)
- `BASH_REMATCH[0]` is the entire matched string, so only output starting from index 1
- use `printf -v myvar ...` instead to store to a variable `myvar` (subject to usual read-loop/subshell behaviour)
- add `printf "\n"` if required

You can make the above work in `zsh` if you use the array `match[]` instead of `BASH_REMATCH[]`, and subtract 1 from all the indexes as `zsh` doesn't keep a 0 element with the entire match.

Comment: +1 Because this should have been the accepted answer but as always, fear of REGEX keeps people from learning what the shell can actually do.

Comment: I just learned that bash can do regex without external commands.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh` only:

```
str=foobarbazblargblurg

set -o extendedglob
printf '%s\n' ${str//(#m)????/$MATCH }
```

Or

```
printf '%s%s%s%s ' ${(s::)str}
```

with `ksh93` only:

```
printf '%s\n' "${str//????/\0 }"
```

With any POSIX shell only (also avoiding the trailing space if the input length is a multiple of 4):

```
out=
while true; do
  case $str in
    (?????*)
      new_str=${str#????}
      out=$out${str%"$new_str"}' '
      str=$new_str
      ;;
    (*)
      out=$out$str
      break
  esac
done
printf '%s\n' "$out"
```

Now, that's for *characters*. If you wanted to do it on grapheme clusters (for instance, to break `Stéphane`, written as `$'Ste\u0301phane'`, as `Stép hane` and not `Ste phan e`), with `zsh`:

```
set -o rematchpcre
str=$'Ste\u301phane' out=
while [[ $str =~ '(\X{4})(.+)' ]] {
  out+="$match[1] " str=$match[2]
}
out+=$str
printf '%s\n' $out
```

With ksh93, you could break by display width as well, which would work for that `Stéphane` above, but could also help when some other sorts of zero-width or double-width characters are involved:

```
str=$'Ste\u301phane' out=
while
  start=${ printf %L.4s. "$str"; }
  start=${start%.}
  [ "$start" != "$str" ]
do
  out+="$start " str=${str#"$start"}
done
out+=$str
printf '%s\n' "$out"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the example using `grep` and `xargs`:

```
$ echo "foobarbazblargblurg" | grep -o .... | xargs
foob arba zbla rgbl
```

Comment: `xargs` runs `echo` by default, so it won't work with words like `-nen` or that contain backslashes depending on the `echo` implementation. You'll see the odd newline character once in  a while as well if xargs runs more than one `echo`. Better to pipe to `paste -sd ' ' -` instead. Note that `-o` is not a standard option.

Comment: `grep -o` is an interesting hack to insert newlines (potentially useful as an alternative to `fold -w 4` if grep handles UTF-8 multibyte characters better), but `xargs` is not a robust or efficient way to convert newlines to spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer by only inserting spaces as required so a space appears at least after every 4 characters on a line; not sure which way you want to handle this case.  For example, given input of "aa bbccdd", you'd get output "aa bbcc dd" rather than "aa b bccd d".

I'm using Perl for lookahead, but I'm not very familiar with Perl in general, so there may be tweaks needed:

```
$ echo "foobarbazblargblurg" | perl -wp -e 's/[^ ]{4}(?=[^\n ])/$& /g'
foob arba zbla rgbl urg

$ echo 'aa bbccdd' | perl -wp -e 's/[^ ]{4}(?=[^\n ])/$& /g'
aa bbcc dd
# not 'aa b bccd d'!

$ echo 'some input' | perl -wp -e 's/[^ ]{4}(?=[^\n ])/$& /g'
some inpu t
# not 'some  inp ut'!

$ echo $'aabb\nc cddee' | perl -wp -e 's/[^ ]{4}(?=[^\n ])/$& /g' | 
> while read; do echo "${REPLY}x"; done
aabbx
c cdde ex
# no spaces added at the end of the first line (while loop to add to the end of
# the line and show this)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by using python

First i am reading file then i am dividing by 4 characters  and adding space

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
b=re.compile(r'[a-z]{4}')

p=open('/root/l.txt','r')
i=p.readlines()
for j in i:
    m=re.findall(b,j)
print " " .join (m) + "  "
```

/root/l.txt==> Consists of the content which you given in example

output

```
foob arba zbla rgbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `split` command. While it is commonly used to split files, you can use it for this as well:

```
split -b 4 --filter='cat;echo -n " "' <<< 'foobarbazblargblurg'
```

I mean it works, but YMMV.