# How to access network without NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, fedora

If I don't have NetworkManager installed on Debian, I edit "**/etc/network/interfaces**" and then run `ifup eth0`. I see that things are different in Fedora 14 (the directory and the command aren't available). How do I do it?

Comment: welcome to the world of learning another distro, and what the real differences are. :P p.s. you don't have to, but I leave questions unanswered for ~24 hours, it gives people a chance to review and upvote things, as peopled tend to look at answered things less I've found.

Comment: @xeno I get it. Well... in this case the solution worked immediately. Not doubts :)

Comment: often they do, I just do it so everyone has a chance to earn points I don't *think* [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5980/29) would have gotten the upvotes it did had I accepted the answer the 5 minutes after I was told the 1 wrong character I did. but as I've said, you can do this however you want, unlike accepting your own answer there's no limits on when you have to do a regular answer. It also gives people a chance to write even better answers.

Comment: @xeno BTW I never hesitate to change Accepted answer whenever a nicer one pitches. Also, luckily Gilles doesn't care whether there already is an accepted answer or not.

Comment: right... I just started doing it because it seems to keep more people (maybe not @gilles) interested for longer. about 1 day  is the max though.

Answer (score 6):

You can continue to use the 'network' service.  Just run

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig network on
```

and

```
sudo /sbin/service network start
```

and it will start the interfaces that are set up in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*.  You might want to check the settings in those files to make sure that the interface you want to start automatically on boot is set "ONBOOT=yes".  For an interface to edit those files, you can use 'system-config-network' which is part of the system-config-network package (if not already installed).

Comment: This is out of date these days. Ever since systemd it's `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl enable network.service` and `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start network.service`.

Comment: Yes, in later versions of Fedora, that's correct.  This was posted in January of 2011, about Fedora 14, which didn't include systemd.

Comment: Yep, I realize that. My comment was more a matter of "This information is old and it's different now." than "Hah, you're wrong, it's this way!". I found it while searching for this information myself, and I just wanted to make sure it stayed up-to-date for future readers.