# Best practices when manually connecting to various wifi networks

Tags: debian, networking, command-line, wifi

How do we manage wireless connections without a network manager?

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253035/20506) excellent answer walked me through connecting to the protected wireless network at home. In short,

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces  # enable dhcp
service networking start
nano /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf  # indicate ssid and password
ifdown wlan0  # name determined by 'ip a show'
ip a flush wlan0
ifup wlan0
wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -c /root/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -B
dhclient wlan0
```

[Another](https://askubuntu.com/a/16588/55633) answer suggests adding this to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address ASSIGNED_IP
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway THE_GATEWAY
wireless-essid YOURSSID
wireless-key WIRELESSKEY_HERE
```

Because over time I will be encountering different networks, with different ssdi and password, I was wondering which would be the best way to approach this, without a network manager. Priorities:

- Don't disclose ssid and passwords if my laptop is compromised - those are sensitive information that people have entrusted me with.
- Don't clutter `/etc` with a ton of custom(user-created) files.
- Don't use high-level utilities, like `network-manager` or `wicd`.

Comment: Read up on roaming mode in the `wpa_supplicant` documentation. That's how I do it on my laptop. The goals "don't store SSID/passwords locally" and "use wpa_supplicant only" are mutually exclusive, though. If you don't want to store SSID/passwords locally, where do you want to store them? Is encrypting the harddisk of your laptop sufficient to allow local storage?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish the conditions:

> Don't disclose ssid and passwords if my laptop is compromised - those are sensitive information that people have entrusted me with.
>
> Don't clutter /etc with a ton of custom(user-created) files.
>
> Don't use high-level utilities, like network-manager or wicd.

You should run `wpa_supplicant` as follows:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c<(wpa_passphrase "Your-SSID" Your-Passwd)
dhclient wlan0
```

You don't need to create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` .

You don't need to store your SSID and Password under `/etc/network/interfaces`

You don't need Network-manager , wicd ...

to correctly connect through `wpa_supplicant` (If you have the NetworkManager installed) , you should stop the `NetworkManager.service` before runing the `wpa_supplicant` command:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: One should point out that under this setup, the user needs to enter SID and password *every single time*, for *all* APs. Also, the command will be visible in bash history etc.

Comment: @dirkt Yes , the weakness of the network command `wpa_passphrase` is displaying the password on the terminal.