# Wi-Fi DHCP debugging for cell phone needed

Tags: wifi, dhcp, android, wireshark

Every then and now, my android cell phone cannot connect to my Wi-Fi and says: unable to obtain IP address. After some time (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours) connection is back to normal.

This is my simplified setup:

Cell phone *--(wireless)--* Wi-Fi router *--(wire)--* DHCP server *--(wire)--* modem

- cell phone: Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9, Kernel 4.4.111-21427293
- Wi-Fi router: Netgear R6260, Router Firmware Version V1.1.0.88_1.0.1
- DHCP server: Debian 9 (Stretch) running isc-dhcpd-4.3.5

I took network dumps from the DHCP server:

- During such a phase of non-connectivity there are no incoming packets.
- When connectivity is back I see both incoming and outgoing DHCP packets.

I therefore tend to rule out the DHCP server as problem source.

The Wi-Fi Router logs: "WLAN access rejected: incorrect security"

I went through the net but have not found anything useful, yet. The Wi-Fi password has not changed, there is no MAC filter or whatsoever. I now suspect that the router does not       forward the DHCP request from cell phone to DHCP server. Therefore, I am trying to tap into to DHCP communication between cell phone and router.

Monitoring Wi-Fi traffic directly on cell phone was without luck: tPacketCapture app does not show DHCP packets, and I have not found anything more useful up to now.

So I use another PC (Ubuntu) sitting in the same Wi-Fi and monitor traffic. What I see is only DHCP requests from the cell phone but no return packets, even if the cell phone is able to connect. I suspect this is because they are no longer broadcast and my Wi-Fi interface filters them because it is not in monitor mode.

Therefore, I would like to switch the Wi-Fi interface of my PC to monitor mode and follow this procedure: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-put-wifi-interface-into-monitor-mode-in-linux/

```
sudo ip link set wlp1s0 down
sudo iw wlp1s0 set monitor none
sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up
```

The output of `sudo iw dev` shows "type monitor" but reverts to "type managed" after few seconds. Some say this is because of the NetworkManager https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330483/wifi-interface-mode-switches-automatically-back-to-managed-ubuntu-20-04 , but disabling the NetworkManager no longer automatically connects to the Wi-Fi.

The wpa_supplicant should solve that: http://greyfocus.com/2018/01/wifi-without-networkmanager/ and [How to setup network without wicd or NetworkManager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253030/how-to-setup-network-without-wicd-or-networkmanager) but eventually I find that also the  wpa_supplicant switches Wi-Fi interface to managed mode and I am not able to sniff the DHCP packets of my cell phone on the Wi-Fi.

---

This is how far I got. All I want is my cell phone to be able to connect reliably to my Wi-Fi.

I'd be greatful if anyone could help here or point me in the right direction how to track this problem down.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Step 1 to troubleshoot: Enable the DHCP server on the Netgear R6260.

Comment: Mats, thank you for that suggestion. I tried, and also here there is no reliable connection.
Any ideas how to capture DHCP traffic between cell phone and router?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install OpenWRT on the Netgear R6260, https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/r6260. OpenWRT is a linux router/firewall distro that can be used on many home routers/firewalls.

Then you have a linux installation that supports `tcpdump` that you can use to capture the traffic with.

See https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/firewall/misc/tcpdump_wireshark