# How to insert newline characters every N chars into a long string

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

Using common bash tools as part of a shell script, I want to repeatedly insert a newline char ('\n') into a long string at intervals of every N chars.

For example, given this string, how would I insert a newline char every 20 chars?

```
head -n 50 /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9
```

Example of the results I am trying to achieve:

```
ZL1WEV72TTO0S83LP2I2
MTQ8DEIU3GSSYJOI9CFE
6GEPWUPCBBHLWNA4M28D
P2DHDI1L2JQIZJL0ACFV
UDYEK7HN7HQY4E2U6VFC
RH68ZZJGMSSC5YLHO0KZ
94LMELDIN1BAXQKTNSMH
0DXLM7B5966UEFGZENLZ
4917Y741L2WRTG5ACFGQ
GRVDVT3CYOLYKNT2ZYUJ
EAVN1EY4O161VTW1P3OY
Q17T24S7S9BDG1RMKGBX
WOZSI4D35U81P68NF5SB
HH7AOYHV2TWQP27A40QC
QW5N4JDK5001EAQXF41N
FKH3Q5GOQZ54HZG2FFZS
Q89KGMQZ46YBW3GVROYH
AIBOU8NFM39RYP1XBLQM
YLG8SSIW6J6XG6UJEKXO
```

A use-case is to quickly make a set of random passwords or ID's of a fixed length. The way I did the above example is:

```
for i in {1..30}; do head /dev/random | tr -dc A-Z0-9 | head -c 20 ; echo ''; done
```

However, for learning purposes, I want to do it a different way. I want to start with an arbitrarily long string and insert newlines, thus breaking one string into multiple small strings of fixed char length.

Comment: `fold -w 20` works. I agree, you should make it an answer.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5980/85039

Comment: The standard utilities are not "`bash` tools".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The venerable [`fold`](https://man.openbsd.org/fold) command ("written by Bill Joy on June 28, 1977") can wrap lines:

```
$ printf "foobarzot\n" | fold -w 3
foo
bar
zot
```

However, there are some edge cases

> BUGS
>        Traditional roff(7) output semantics, implemented both by GNU nroff and
>        by mandoc(1), only uses a single backspace for backing up the previous
>        character, even for double-width characters.  The fold backspace
>        semantics required by POSIX mishandles such backspace-encoded sequences,
>        breaking lines early.  The fmt(1) utility provides similar functionality
>        and does not suffer from that problem, but isn't standardized by POSIX.

so if your input has backspace characters you may need to filter or remove those

```
$ printf "a\bc\bd\be\n" | col -b | fold -w 1
e
$ printf "a\bc\bd\be\n" | tr -d "\b" | fold -w 1
a
c
d
e
```

Answer (score 20):

I like the `fold` answer but just in case you want with `sed`, here it is:

```
sed 's/.\{20\}/&\
/g' filename
```

You can use `-i` for in-place insertion.

Comment: thanks. I voted your answer up, but I like the `fold` solution too.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the contents in a variable, such as:

```
var=$(head -n 50 /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9)
```

Then you could use a bash loop over the length of the variable in chunks of 20, printing out each chunk:

```
for((start=1;start < ${#var}; start += 20)); do printf '%s\n' "${var:start:20}"; done
```

If you want them as individual variables, consider assigning the output to an array:

```
readarray -t passwords < <(for((start=1;start < ${#var}; start += 20)); do printf '%s\n' "${var:start:20}"; done)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that `tr -dc` thing to get rid of non-printable chars, I would just use `base64` from coreutils:

```
$ base64 -w20 /dev/urandom | head -8
ckXkWvb0zJknz2zi4fRS
3Jv0dDbKiX8fef7SOfbH
QJySlGUzzhi32wvrGliK
YEiuz6v+EFaRYRMjvnJq
HCXIPiP9wmgONLRqm9uK
iHYwo5xIs8gGjQQEQBeX
8NkL4EkmOAHdmWhGvZYl
AcxD2DaTq2TZRsDL+UMx
```

If the `+` and `/` are problem you can replace them:

```
$ base64 -w20 /dev/urandom | tr +/ pq | head -8
zr7MgiEr7xBd7h9ihK30
IRNvDuT2H9HsHVq9yFqh
S1cihgfAInjfFspMNXVC
qUUwGErD7nZqtzQtLOo7
DNDp4TVWvHmbEh7HLDGX
GtqqDdEoceY8m5U7FGu0
TvGtTukm6Whr7VHN1mZG
DW5TUH525IA52zLKYACV
```

Comment: #!/bin/ksh

## Usage: ./$0 <file>
## Converts a certificate stored as one string with no headers into a normal 64-byte wide file with proper header and footer.

echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
sed 's/.\{64\}/&\
/g' $1
echo "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"